# Teamcity when updating from MySQL 5.7 to 8 we get query_cache_size error

Tags: mysql, jdbc, amazon-rds, teamcity, mysql-connector

When we updated our TeamCity RDS/Database from MySQL 5.7 to 8 on reboot we got the error

> jetbrains.buildServer.STARTUP - Unexpected exception: SQL error when doing 'Taking a connection from the data source': java.sql.SQLException: Unknown system variable 'query_cache_size'

We tried changing our `database.properties` file to disable query caching with this but still has the same error in the logs.

> connectionUrl=jdbc:mysql://NAME-ID.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306/teamcity?useSSL=false&disableQueryCache=true

We are running the Docker image provided by TeamCity so it should have the correct drivers installed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question in case others run into this issue.

With the TeamCity docker images you need to make sure you have the correct JDBC jar installed to this location `/data/teamcity_server/datadirlib/jdbc/<filename>.jar` To download the file you can run a wget like this `wget https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/mysql/mysql-connector-java/8.0.30/mysql-connector-java-8.0.30.jar` and on reboot it should automatically pick up the file that there.